# I can't get object from JSON array

Tags: java, android, json

[This is the JSON URL](https://api.github.com/events)

I want to get all object in **actor**, how can I do that?

```
private void parseJSON() {
    String url = "https://api.github.com/events";

    final JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                   try{
                       JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("actor");

                       for(int i =0; i <jsonArray.length();i ++){
                           JSONObject act = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                           int id = act.getInt("id");
                           String imageUrl = act.getString("avatar_url");
                           String login = act.getString("login");
                           String displaylogin = act.getString("display_login");
                           String gravatar_id = act.getString("gravatar_id");
                           String url = act.getString("url");
```

Comment: What problem are you having specifically?

Comment: `actor` is an entry in every item in the array. Which one do you want to get?

Comment: i run it then nothing show on screen. I want to know actor is array or object and how can i get all for loop and show in RecyclerView. sorry My English is not so good.

Comment: Have you tried compiling a small Java program to do this independently of an Android application? Maybe it would be easier to debug it that way.

Answer (score 1):

`actor` is not an array.

You can read `actor` something like

```java
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class JacksonExample2 {

    private static final String jsonStr = "YOUR JSON";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JSONException {
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonStr);
        for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++) {
            JSONObject item = (JSONObject) jsonArray.get(i);
            JSONObject actor = (JSONObject) item.get("actor");
            // You can read all properties of actor like 'actor.getString("avatar_url");'
            System.out.println(actor);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**actor** is not `Array` type.
Create field actor with `Array` type and store data.